# How to load a property value of an object from database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to pass a list of string to dropdownlist in my view. when I am passing this list as hard coded I am getting values in dropdownlist but I want to pass this list of strings from database. Following is my model class.

```
public  class League
{       
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string LeagueName { get; set; }
    public string Icon { get; set; }   
}
```

and action is as

```
public ActionResult Index()
{           
    var leagues= new List<string> { "STAR", "GOLD", "SILVER" };
    var leagueOptions = new SelectList(leagues);
    ViewBag.leagues = leagueOptions;            
    return View();
}
```

till now everything is fine but I want to build a `List<LeagueName> leagues = new LeagueName();` from my model class but do not know hot to query this.

Comment: Assuming your using EF, then `var leagues = db.Leagues.Select(x => x.LeagueName);` (but why would you not want the `Id` property as well?)

Comment: Use LINQ ? SQL ? You query your db and store the result in a `new list<League>` ?

Comment: Add code of Index.cshtml

Comment: `List<League> leagues = new List<League>()` and then followed by `var leagueName = leagues.Where([condition]).Select(x => x.LeagueName).ToList()` just enough. Note that LeagueName is a property of class League, you should build a list from parent class that wraps your property.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have implemented as you guided me. I am getting all values in my drop down list but when I am debugging then I am getting nothing in var leagues. I dont know why. please help.. I want to share screen shots of what I am getting but dont know hot to share images in comments.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your comment. If all the values are in the dropdown then `leagues` is populated (that's where they come from)

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto Please explain why to use .Where([condition]) ..... I am not getting the concept of why to use condition.... I want to get all records to build up list

Comment: @Sulaiman, If you want all records, then don't use `.Where()` (that's only if you wanted to filter the results)

Comment: @Sulaiman: `Where([condition])` only used if you have certain criteria(s) to filter a select query. If you have no criteria to filter results, just directly use `leagues.Select(x => x.LeagueName)`. Condition(s) to apply expressed by lambda with boolean result, e.g. `Where(x => x.Id == leagueId)`.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Is there any way to send you image of what I am getting during debugging???? Actually when I was debugging I was not getting any record in variable "var leagues" , unintentionally I pressed continue button in visual studio then I saw all records populated in dropdownlist.......

Comment: Upload it to [imgur](http://imgur.com/) and post the link.

Comment: @StephenMuecke please have a look http://imgur.com/gallery/BN6SJvO/new

Comment: That's just giving you the information about the actual query definition. You can always use `var leagues = db.Leagues.Select(x => x.LeagueName).ToList();` to materialize the query to an in-memory set and then inspect it.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks dear.....http://imgur.com/gallery/Bj3GmyP/new

Comment: I want "Id" of League  when I pass "Name" of a specific League.

Comment: @Sulaiman, That's what I noted in one of my previous comments :) Change it to `ViewBag.leagues =  db.Leagues.Select(x => new SelectListItem(){ Value = x.Id.ToString(), Text = x.LeagueName };`

Comment: @StephenMuecke     I want "Id" of League  when I pass "Name" of a specific League. I tried following query but I am getting object based on passed "Name" of League rather than "Id" ...... public JsonResult GetId(string LeagueName)  {
            HostBoostersDBEntities db = new HostBoostersDBEntities();
            var leagueId = db.Leagues.Where(lg => lg.LeagueName == LeagueName).ToList();  {read next comment please}        
            return Json(leagueDivisions, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }              please have a look http://imgur.com/gallery/FV88f3m/new

Comment: @StephenMuecke         { Here I have object of League class in leagueId.. I want to extract just Id of it because I want to use this Id in my further logic block..Actually I want to use this Id to get LeagueDivisions to populate cascade dropdownlist }

Comment: Refer the code in [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1bPZym) if you want to understand how to implement cascading dropdownlists

Comment: @StephenMuecke I am populating first dropdown list by league names using var leagues = db.Leagues.Select(x => x.League1).ToList(); and when I click on list option leaguedivision should be populated.. to do this I am getting the name of that selected league in my action and want to get id of that so that I can do another qery to get list of leaguedivisions like in next comment

Comment: @StephenMuecke   public JsonResult GetStates(string country)
        {
            HostBoostersDBEntities db = new HostBoostersDBEntities();
            var leagueId = db.Leagues.Where(lg => lg.League1 == country).ToList();
            List<LeagueDivision> leagueDivisions = db.LeagueDivisions.Where(lgdiv => lgdiv.LeagueId == 1).ToList();            
            return Json(leagueDivisions, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }     I am stuck and dont know how to fix the problem.. please guide

Comment: @Sulaiman, You cannot keep putting comments in code - you don't even format them and they are unreadable.  And I have given you a link to a fiddle showing how to do this the right way - study it and then study it again, and then study it once more. Then if you having problems, ask a new question.

Comment: @StephenMuecke sory for intrupting, I wil study fidle, I want to ask last question..why compiler is showing eror "opreator ==  cant be applied to operands of type int and string"... please check image      http://imgur.com/gallery/Y24qXdZ/new

Comment: Because `LeagueId` is an `int?` and `Id` is a `string` (you added `.ToString()` in the previous line. Just remove the `.ToString()` (and stop using `var`. If you want to understand your code, explicitly define your variables - i.e. use `int Id = db.Leagues.Where(....`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I studied  the fiddle you mentioned in last comment...well explanatory...I have implemented this approach in my scenario but I am getting web http exception in dropdownlist....can you explain why it is so and hot to handle it....??

Comment: @Sulaiman, I can't guess without seeing your code. This question has nothing to do with cascading dropownlists, so suggest you ask a new question showing the relevant code you have used.

Comment: @StephenMuecke please check it out   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38167829/why-web-http-exvception-is-heppening-when-i-am-populating-a-drop-down-list

Comment: @StephenMuecke  can you guide me regarding this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38311591/how-to-get-a-property-value-from-database-based-on-cascaded-drop-down-list-selec

Comment: @Singh   can you guide me regarding this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38311591/how-to-get-a-property-value-from-database-based-on-cascaded-drop-down-list-selec

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto   can you guide me regarding this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38311591/how-to-get-a-property-value-from-database-based-on-cascaded-drop-down-list-selec