# Why is this web http exception happening when I am populating a drop down list?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, drop-down-menu

**Model**

`League` and `LeagueDivision` are two model classes

```
public class League
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string League1 { get; set; }
    public string Icon { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<LeagueDivision> LeagueDivisions { get; set; }
}

public class LeagueDivision
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> LeagueId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Icon { get; set; }

    public virtual League League { get; set; }
} 

  public class ViewModelForHostBooster
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter price")]
        [Display(Name = "Price")]
        public decimal Price { get; set; }       

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a league")]
        [Display(Name = "League")]

        public int? SelectedLeague { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a league division")]
        [Display(Name = "League Division")]

        public int? SelectedLeagueDivision { get; set; }

        public SelectList LeagueList { get; set; }
        public SelectList LeagueDivisionList { get; set; }      


    }
```

**Controller**

In `IndexDropdown` action I am just populating view with model and validating if 
the model is validated then populate the view otherwise return the view. In `FetchLeagueDivision` action I am selecting Id and Name properties of model class based on passed argument ID.

Can anybody guide me why a `WebHttpException` is happening when I run this piece of code? Here is a link of exception [Http Exception Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BKmS.png)

```
public class DropDownController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult IndexDropDown()
    {
        ViewModelForHostBooster model = new ViewModelForHostBooster();

        ConfigureViewModel(model);
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult IndexDropDown(ViewModelForHostBooster model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ConfigureViewModel(model);
            return View(model);
        }

        // save and redirect
        return RedirectToAction("Somewhere");
    }


    private void ConfigureViewModel(ViewModelForHostBooster model)
    {
        HostBoostersDBEntities db = new HostBoostersDBEntities();

        var leagues = db.Leagues.Select(x => new { Value = x.Id, Text = x.League1 }).ToList();
        model.LeagueList = new SelectList(leagues, "Id", "League1");

        if (model.SelectedLeague.HasValue)
        {
            IEnumerable<LeagueDivision> leaguedivisions = db.LeagueDivisions.Where(l => l.LeagueId == model.SelectedLeague.Value);
            model.LeagueDivisionList = new SelectList(leaguedivisions, "Id", "Name");
        }
        else
        {
            model.LeagueDivisionList = new SelectList(Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>());
        }
    }
}
```

**View**

```
@model HostBooster.Models.ViewModelForHostBooster
 @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <div>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Price)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Price)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Price)
        </div>

        <div>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SelectedLeague)
```

> **exception is occurring here** @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedLeague, Model.LeagueList)

```
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedLeague, Model.LeagueList)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SelectedLeague)
        </div>
        <div>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SelectedLeagueDivision)
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedLeagueDivision, Model.LeagueDivisionList)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SelectedLeagueDivision)
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="save" />
    }
```

Comment: Please update ViewModelForHostBooster.

Comment: @StephenMuecke   http://imgur.com/gallery/EnRhw00/new   this is the definition of viewmodel.  I am trying to share another image of exception but imgur is not allowing me... I just  share one image and getting message that m sharing too fast please wait 50 mints

Comment: @StephenMuecke  DataBinding: '<>f__AnonymousType0`2[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]' does not contain a property with the name 'Id'.    this is the error message in browser

Comment: @StephenMuecke exception is occurring on line (59)    Line 57:         <div>
Line 58:             @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SelectedLeague)
Line 59:             @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedLeague, Model.LeagueList)
Line 60:             @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SelectedLeague)
Line 61:         </div>

Comment: @StephenMuecke  dear I am sorry, I could not understand you comment "
 
It needs to go in your question (links to images of code relevant to the question are not acceptable) "

Comment: @StephenMuecke   oh I am really sorry....I understand...so what  is the right way to put code second time.how I can share my code again if I am being asked to do so..

Comment: @StephenMuecke I am sorry if I am interrupting you. Actually I am new to this platform and dont know much..but want to learn how it works. I will edit my questing accordingly. you asked me to remove close vote but m sorry what does it mean.. can you please tell what I am supposed to do

Comment: @StephenMuecke I edited my question and waiting to read guidance from you. I have to submit this task to my teacher please guide me so that I can complete it in time....Thanks

Comment: @alisoltani   I updated view model class. please have a look and guide me how to solve this exception

Comment: @StephenMuecke  ok dear,  thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In view  `Model.LeagueList` is null. It should not be null.
if edit view code like this(for example), Works well:

```
<body>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    List<SelectListItem> listItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
    listItems.Add(new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = "Example1",
        Value = "Example1"
    });
    listItems.Add(new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = "Example2",
        Value = "Example2",
        Selected = true
    });
    listItems.Add(new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = "Example3",
        Value = "Example3"
    });


    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Price)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Price)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Price)
    </div>

    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SelectedLeague)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedLeague, listItems)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SelectedLeague)
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SelectedLeagueDivision)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedLeagueDivision, Model.LeagueDivisionList)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SelectedLeagueDivision)
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="save" />
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you guidance.. I have implemented successfully...now I am trying to implement Httppost method for that but getting exception.  Please check this link and guide me how to handle this exception  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38180372/system-data-entity-infrastructure-dbupdateconcurrencyexception-store-update-in

Comment: @Sulaiman please upvote and accept this answer if this answer helps you, so people know this is the correct answer.