# How to get a property value from database based on cascaded drop down list selected values??

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, getjson

> I want to get a property of an entity based on passing id's of selected items from cascaded dropdown list...On every change in level 1 or in level 2 of cascaded drop down list, price must be updated.

I have implemented cascaded drop down list. On page load **Leaguedropdown (Level 1)** populates and second **LeagueDivisiondropdown (Level 2)** populates when I select any item from Level 1. I have to implement **Price Calculator** which  should calculate price value depending upon selected items from cascaded drop down list, all prices are stored in database and I am using Entity Framework. 
I am using .change() method and sending getJson request for Level 2 which is working fine. I also want same functionality on Level 1 but I already used .change() method to populate LeagueDivision so I don't have idea how to implement this on Level 1 too.

I will appreciate if some one will guide me and will be thankful.

**Here is View and Script**

```
<body>
<p id="message"></p>
@using (Html.BeginForm("PriceCalculatorIndex", "PriceCalculator", FormMethod.Post,
                                      new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{

    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SelectedLeague, new { @class = "control-lebel" })
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedLeague, Model.LeagueList, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SelectedLeague)
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SelectedLeagueDivision, new { @class = "control-lebel" })
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedLeagueDivision, Model.LeagueDivisionList, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SelectedLeagueDivision)
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Price)
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Price)
    </div>
}
<!-- JS includes -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/4.0/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var leaguedivisionUrl = '@Url.Action("Fetchleaguedivision")';
    var updatePrice = '@Url.Action("updatePrice")';
    var divisions = $('#SelectedLeagueDivision');
    $('#SelectedLeague').change(function () {
        divisions.empty();
        $.getJSON(leaguedivisionUrl, { ID: $(this).val() }, function (data) {
            if (!data) {
                return;
            }
            divisions.append($('<option></option>').val());
            $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                divisions.append($('<option></option>').val(item.Value).text(item.Text));
            });
        });
    });

    $('#SelectedLeagueDivision').change(function () {

        $.getJSON(updatePrice, { LeagueDivisionId: $(this).val(), LeagueId: $('#SelectedLeague').val() }, function (data) {
            if (!data) {
                return;
            }
            alert(data);
            //document.getElementById('#message').innerHTML = data;
        });
    });
</script>
```

**JSON Result to fetch price from database**

```
 public JsonResult updatePrice(int LeagueId, int LeagueDivisionId)
    {

        HostBoostersDBEntities2 db = new HostBoostersDBEntities2();
        CalculatorPrice updatedPrice = db.CalculatorPrices
           .Where(x => x.LeagueId == LeagueId
               &&
               x.LeagueDivisionId == LeagueDivisionId)
               .FirstOrDefault();
        decimal updatedPriceToView = (decimal)updatedPrice.Price;
        return Json(updatedPriceToView.ToString(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: You can make multiple ajax calls in your `$('#SelectedLeague').change()` function (just copy the `$.getJSON(updatePrice....` code after the `$.getJSON(leaguedivisionUrl, ...` code (but modify the values your sending). But you need to consider what happens when the value of `SelectedLeagueDivision` is `null` - it will throw an exception because the parameter is `int` and is required.

Comment: @StephenMuecke please have a look on my answer...I appreciate  you guidance and seeking further guidance from your side....thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have implemented successfully in this way.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("PriceCalculatorIndex", "PriceCalculator", FormMethod.Post,
                                      new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{

    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SelectedLeague, new { @class = "control-lebel" })
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedLeague, Model.LeagueList, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SelectedLeague)
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SelectedLeagueDivision, new { @class = "control-lebel" })
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedLeagueDivision, Model.LeagueDivisionList, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SelectedLeagueDivision)
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>
            price :
        </label>
        <span id="spPrice"></span>
    </div>
}
<!-- JS includes -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/4.0/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        LoadDivisionsAndPrice()
    });
    var leaguedivisionUrl = '@Url.Action("Fetchleaguedivision")';
    var updatePrice = '@Url.Action("updatePrice")';
    var divisions = $('#SelectedLeagueDivision');
    $('#SelectedLeague').change(function () {
        LoadDivisionsAndPrice();
    });
    $('#SelectedLeagueDivision').change(function () {
        LoadPrice();
    });
    function LoadPrice() {
        $.getJSON(updatePrice, { LeagueId: $('#SelectedLeague').val(), LeagueDivisionId: $('#SelectedLeagueDivision').val() }, function (data) {
            if (!data) {
                return;
            }
            document.getElementById('spPrice').innerText = data.Price;
        });
    }
    function LoadDivisionsAndPrice()
    {
        divisions.empty();
        $.getJSON(leaguedivisionUrl, { ID: $('#SelectedLeague').val() }, function (data) {
            if (!data) {
                return;
            }
            divisions.append($('<option></option>').val());
            $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                divisions.append($('<option></option>').val(item.Value).text(item.Text));
            });
            LoadPrice();
        });
    }        
</script>
```

Comment: There is no need to call `LoadDivisionsAndPrice()` when the page first loads (those values should already be in the model when the page first loads). And you have a potential problem with `LoadPrice()` because the value of `SelectedLeagueDivision` can be `null` which would throw an exception in your `updatePrice()` method. Check that both `SelectedLeague` and `SelectedLeagueDivision` are not null before calling the controller method.

Comment: @StephenMuecke without calling `LoadDivisionsAndPrice()` on first load just `League` loads...I want to load every thing that was why I called...now I am trying again without calling `LoadDivisionsAndPrice` just `League` loads.

Comment: Then you have a problem with your GET method. If `SelectedLeague` has a value, then `Model.LeagueDivisionList` should be populated with the relevant `SelectList`. Ditto `Price` should be populated in the GET method based on the values of `SelectedLeague` and `SelectedLeagueDivision`. To send a view to the browsers, then immediately make another call back to the server because you 'forgot' to send the correct data in the first place is pointless.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Remember, you taught me right way to implement cascaded drop down list from your fiddle in which nothing populates on first page load....it just shows `please select city`, after selection of `city`, `locality` populates and then `sub-locality` on selection of `locality`....but I want to implement the behavior as in this link    https://hotsboosters.com/boosting    I am sorry, I think I could not convey my point that is why sharing this link so that you can understand what I want to implement and I am getting same behavior by calling `LoadDivisionsAndPrice()` on first load

Comment: You need to go back and study the [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1bPZym) - in particular the code in the `ConfigureViewModel()` method :) Do not call `LoadDivisionsAndPrice` when the view is first loaded because those values should already be loaded if you code in the GET method is correct.

Comment: @StephenMuecke as I am beginner and don't know right and standard way that is why seeking help....I am learning day by day and really appreciate your guidance

Comment: @StephenMuecke dear can you guide me from where I can learn `drag and drop controls` for view...for example, suppose I have a sql table named `student` with `studentId`, `studentName`, `studentAge` etc etc...I have shown list of `student objects` in my view.....I want to drag and drop these objects in list view. for example if I drag `10th list item` and drop it to `5th` place then it should be placed there and `Id's` of these list items should be changed in database.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks for your guidance...I have implemented successfully jQuery sortable....Now I want to update database with new sorted order....I am searching and studying from internet....I will appreciate if you recommend some studies to do this.

Comment: I cant give you any without seeing your code and what your doing. You need to ask a new question with the relevant details :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke dear I have implemented `sortable list` and successfully `updated database` as I wanted...now want to learn `Pay Pall Merchant` for my shopping app....I will be thankful to you from core of my heart if you `recommend` me some studies or rightful tutorial from where I can learn it from scratch as I am a newbie in this arena....`bundle of thanks`

Comment: Sorry, I have not used Pay Pall Merchant so I cant really recommend anything.

Comment: @StephenMuecke  its ok

Comment: @StephenMuecke Help please    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38434937/how-to-link-a-cascaded-drop-down-list-to-another-cascaded-drop-down-list

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code. Give reference of my javascript comments where you think I have still mis-understood the question.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var leaguedivisionUrl = '@Url.Action("Fetchleaguedivision")';
    var updatePrice = '@Url.Action("updatePrice")';
    var divisions = $('#SelectedLeagueDivision');

    function bindLeagueDivisionData(data) {
        divisions.empty();
        $.each(data, function(index, item) {
            divisions.append($('<option></option>').val(item.Value).text(item.Text));
        });
    }

    function getUpdatedPrice(leagueId, divisionId) {
        $.getJSON(updatePrice, {
            LeagueDivisionId: divisionId,
            LeagueId: leagueId
        }, function(data) {
            if (!data) {
                return;
            }
            alert(data);
            //document.getElementById('#message').innerHTML = data;
        });
    }

    $('#SelectedLeague').change(function() {
        if (divisions.find("option").length == 0) {
            /*The division list is empty, fetch the divisions*/
            $.getJSON(leaguedivisionUrl, {
                ID: $(this).val()
            }, function(data) {
                if (!data) {
                    return;
                }
                /*Once division data is bound, get the price for the league and first selected division. If you choose to leave first division as empty, your wish; just remove the contents of done in that case*/
                $.when(bindLeagueDivisionData(data)).done(function() {
                    getUpdatedPrice($(this).val(), $('#SelectedLeagueDivision'));
                });
            });
        } else {
            /*Divisions are already present just get the price for the combination*/
            getUpdatedPrice($(this).val(), $('#SelectedLeagueDivision'));
        }
    });

    $('#SelectedLeagueDivision').change(function() {
        /*Get the price for the combination*/
        getUpdatedPrice($('#SelectedLeague').val(), $(this).val());
    });
</script>
```

Comment: here is what I want....if I have 5 Leagues and 5 Leagues divisions then total combinations are 25 meaning 25 different prices are stored in a sql table. I want to update price on every change in League or in LeagueDivisions......both drop down list are working fine but I want to learn how to get values from database depending upon these 25 combinations

Comment: @ajaysinghdav10d....for example if I select League = Bronze and LeageDivision = LeagueDivision1 then it should update price.....and if I only change selection of League = Gold and LeageDivision = LeagueDivision1 remains same it should find that record accordingly and so on......

Comment: @ajaysinghdav10d.....dear its not working as you guided.... I have implemented it other way

Comment: @ajaysinghdav10d...I really appreciate your effort...thanks...please have a look on my answer and guide me is there any other optimal way....any how I got what I wanted

Comment: Hi Sulaiman, Your answer is OK as long as it serves the purpose. Just one question though, the first call to LoadPrice will not return anything because your Division's first element is blank. Is that the intended behaviour?